# Possibility to get a J1 Visa despite parents in USA?

Tags: usa, visa

I'm a 3rd year computer-science student and I've got a tech (software) internship at a very well known, top American company in Silicon Valley.

I'm currently studying at a top Canadian institution (but I'm an Indian/Chinese citizen).

I've got the DS2019 and all documents, but my parents are diplomats (foreign service) currently posted in the US. Could this be a problem?

I don't intend to settle in the US because I have to come back and finish my degree, is this enough proof to not be considered in 214(b)?

I'm just worried my parents will be a problem even though they are diplomat officials who will leave the US in 2021.

Comment: Indian/Chinese citizen? India does not recognize dual citizenship. Do you hold an Indian passport or Chinese one?

Comment: @MichaelHampton the most likely problem is that immediate family of A-1 diplomats must be admitted in A-1 status (unless they independently qualify for G status).  Full-time students are counted as immediate family until age 23, and in some cases beyond.  If OP is in A-1 status, it will be necessary to involve the Indian embassy and the State Department in an application for an employment authorization document.  It is all very much off topic for [Travel.SE].  The question belongs on [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: I migrated this question but it seems it is already also asked and answered here. Please close and we will deleted it on travel.